# How much space do I need to grow a dark oak tree with saplings?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know that it needs 7 blocks above, but I wanted to know how much it requires next to it. For example, can I put one dark oak (unobstructed) every block? Every other block? Every 5 blocks? This is for a manual tree farm. Are there any other requirements as well? I saw that the base doesn't need any space but the top does somewhere and haven't seen it since. How should I grow my dark oak?

Comment: Why don't you literally just test it?

Comment: Well I'm lazy and I want reputation, as well as to help others having the same problem, so here I am @theonlygusti

Comment: Of course, you could answer your *own* question, thus getting more reputation, assuming that over-balances the laziness...

Comment: You're not wrong lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Minecraft Wiki found [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sapling):

> Dark oak needs at least 7 spaces above **(4×4 column)** and must be
> planted as 4 saplings in a 2×2 square.

So, having four blocks of available space around the saplings should be sufficient.

Comment: Four blocks of space including the saplings (like plant a two-by-two with one block around it everywhere) or four blocks of space on each side (plant a two-by-two with four blocks around it everywhere)? I'm guessing it's the first, but thanks!

Comment: @TheCodedMasterCubing I believe it is the first option you gave.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: You are welcome. :)